# Screenshot to Flickr

Tags: macos, screenshot, flickr

Anyone know of a good (or any) Mac utility to take screenshots and immediately save them to a Flickr account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I'll go with [LittleSnapper](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/).

Comment: Ha. Didn't get to use this for a while, and LS was off. Got into this whole dilemma again, until the vague memory of this conversation became clear. Loading Little Snapper :)

Answer (score 7):

How about Skitch? Its [feature list](http://skitch.com/features) specifically mentions sharing to Flickr.

Answer (score 1):

[Courier](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/courier/) is a generic uploading utility to several services.

If you only need basic functionality, you can try creating an Automator workflow using [Flickr upload automator action](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/automator/flickruploadautomatoraction.html), and the basic *"Get ... Finder Items"* actions.

You can use [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) with a rule on the Desktop to initiate the Automator workflow, so that any and all screenshots get uploaded automatically.

Answer (score 1):

iMacros for Firefox (and Chrome) can do this. It is like Automator, but for the web browser and cross-platform.

http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/

Comment: Sounds intersting since it is cross-platform. Thanks! 
But therefore you need to configure it first, right? I haven't found a simple tutorial via Google.